# please give one scenario when to use spark-submit --files

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark

when to use --files with spark-submit. what will happen internally?
Sorry to ask this basic question but I did not find much documentation about --files
please provide any example or scenario..

Thanks in adv,

Answer (score 0):

You can see details about an option by doing `spark-submit --help`. Here is what it says which is pretty clear. You can use it for resolving a file dependency, example - distributing a config file while submitting the application.

```
--files FILES               Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working
                              directory of each executor. File paths of these files
                              in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).
```